# Using Repeater and jQuery together

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, clientid

I examine lots of blogs answers about my question also I found some solution from this site and I tried all of them. But I don't know why is it? These solutions are not fix my problem I get errors always.
   Finally, I found a solution that I recognize that is true, because in many place this solution is accepted. But this cannot solve my problem again.

```
$("#<%=plusBttn.ClientID%>")
```

I get this error when I tried this solution : plusBttn does not exist in the current context.

I use predictable mode for client mode for my buttons and textbox. Simply, I want to change quantity , which shown in a textbox(QuantityTxtbx), with control my buttons (minusBttn for decrease the value of quantityTxtbx value and plusBttn similarly use for increase the value)

Actually my problem is in the find my controls by using ClientID in jscript.

Codes the shown above are all in the Repeater,ItemTemplate:

My jscript code in asp.net page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#<%=plusBttn.ClientID%>").click(function () {
      var value = parseInt($("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val());
      value = value + 1;
      $("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val(value);
      });

     $("input[id$='#minusBttn_']").click(function () {
                var value = parseInt($("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val());
                                    if (value > 1)
                                        value = value - 1;
                                    $("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val(value);
                                });
                            });
```

And my controls ;

```
    <asp:Button ID="minusBttn" runat="server" Text="-"  ClientIDMode="Predictable"/> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTxtbx" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' Enabled="False" EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="False" Height="16px" Width="16px" Wrap="False"ClientIDMode="Predictable">1</asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="plusBttn" runat="server" Text="+" ClientIDMode="Predictable" />
```

Ok sorry for misunderstanding, Here is the my browser side code:

```
<script type="text/jscript">

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            var plusBttn = $("input[id$='minusBttn']");
                            $("input[id$='#minusBttn_']").click(function () {
                                var value = parseInt($("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val());
                                value = value + 1;
                                $("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val(value);

                            });
                            $("input[id$='#minusBttn_']").click(function () {
                                var value = parseInt($("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val());
                                if (value > 1)
                                    value = value - 1;
                                $("input[id$='QuantityTxtbx']").val(value);
                            });
                        });

                    </script>

                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl01$minusBttn" value="-" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_ctl01_minusBttn_0" /> 


                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl01$QuantityTxtbx" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_ctl01_QuantityTxtbx_0" disabled="disabled" style="height:16px;width:16px;" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl01$plusBttn" value="+" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_ctl01_plusBttn_0" />
```

Comment: what does output html and script look like in browser source?

Comment: They are in repeater and in a table. This buttons and textbox that I talked about in a same td.

Comment: jscript that I used for just control them. (To change textbox value)

Comment: idea was for you to provide the live html... describing it in words doesn't help. Browser doesn't work with your asp code... it works with the output html and script

Comment: I try but I cannot post image :S  system don't allow me

Comment: Isn't my question is clear eneough? You can ask more question then. I need help!

Comment: image?  You need to post the code. This isn't 20 questions...  provide html and script that browser sees, not your server side version... that's not complicated

Comment: ok I update my question you can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code:

```
$("#<%#Container.FindControl("plusBttn").ClientID%>")
```

We already know the master page chagnes ID's based on content `ContentPlaceHolder` and with the repeater it iterates new ID's for anything your database connection. the jquery `.FindControl` works good with your databound plusBttn ClientID's.

then update your jquery script to maybe:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var plusBttn = $("#<%#Container.FindControl("plusBttn").ClientID%>");
 $("#<%#Container.FindControl("minusBttn").ClientID%>").click(function () {
     $("#<%#Container.FindControl("QuantityTxtbx").ClientID%>").val();
  });
 $("#<%#Container.FindControl("minusBttn").ClientID%>").click(function () {
     $("#<%#Container.FindControl("QuantityTxtbx").ClientID%>").val();
  });
});
```